# Can't send data to API server 'Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed'

Tags: javascript, html, angular, api

I want to send and receive data from an API server , when I send data from Postman it shows in the app put if I input from the app it doesn't show up, I'm getting the following error `Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed`. I've attached all the files, I'm using the latest Angular version

```js
   

 import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
    import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    import { HttpService } from '../http.service';
    import { Todo } from './todo';


    @Component({
      // tslint:disable-next-line: component-selector
      selector: 'todo-app',
      templateUrl: './todo-app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./todo-app.component.css']
    })
    export class TodoAppComponent implements OnInit {

    myForm: FormGroup;
    todoitems = [];
    todolist;
    submitted = false;

      constructor(private router: Router, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private httpService: HttpService ) {
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
           todoitems : [this.todolist, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)])]

        });

        this.httpService.gettodo()
        .subscribe
        (
          (      data: Todo[])=>
          {
            this.todoitems = data;
          }

        );

          this.todoitems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todoitems'));
      }

      get todoForms() {
        return this.myForm.get('todoitems') as FormArray;
      }

      addTodo(todolist) {

        if (this.myForm.invalid) {
          this.submitted = true;

      }
        if (this.myForm.valid) {
            console.log('Form Submitted!');
            this.myForm.reset();
            this.todoitems.push(todolist);
            console.log(this.todoitems);
            this.submitted = false;
           
            const newHero: Todo = { name } as Todo;
        this.httpService
          .addTodoo(newHero)
          .subscribe
        (
          (      data: Todo[])=>
          {
            this.todoitems = data;
          }

        );
         
      }
                  
        localStorage.setItem('todoitems', JSON.stringify(this.todoitems));

      }

      deletetodo(index) {
          this.todoitems.splice(index, 1);
          localStorage.setItem('todoitems', JSON.stringify(this.todoitems));

    }

    }
```

```css
    


    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    var cors = require('cors')

    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(cors())

    const names = []

    app.get('/api/names', (req, res) => {
        res.send(names);
    }
    );

    app.post('/api/names', (req, res) => {
        const name = {
            id: names.length,
            name :req.body.name
            
        };
        names.push(name);
        res.send(name);

    });

    app.put('/api/names/:id', (req , res) => {

        const name = {
            name :req.body.name
        };
        names.push(name);
        res.send(name);

    });

    app.delete('/api/names/:id', (req , res) => {

        const index = names.indexOf(name);
        names.splice(index ,1 );
        res.send(name);




    });

    app.listen(3000, () => console.log('port 3000'));
```

```html
    <form [formGroup]="myForm">

        <div class="input">

            <input formControlName="todoitems"  [(ngModel)]="todolist"  name="todoitems">
            <button  type="submit" (click)="addTodo(todolist)">Add</button >
                <div>
                <div *ngIf="submitted && myForm.controls.todoitems.errors">
                    <div *ngIf="myForm.controls.todoitems.errors.required"> please fill</div>
                    <div *ngIf="myForm.controls.todoitems.errors.minlength">min 3</div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    <br>
               <div>
            <table style="width:50%">
            <tr *ngFor="let todoitem of todoitems; let i = index">
             <td>{{ todoitem }}</td>

             <td>
                    <button (click)="deletetodo(i)">Delete</button>
             </td>
            </tr>




         </table>
        </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: `this.todoitems = data;` Please `console.log(data)` and show

Comment: why when get data from server with gettodo  In the same moment again get from localStorage ?  always get data from localstorage . because httpService.gettodo() and getfromLocalStorage runing synchronous .

Comment: Yes, please show what you have in `this.todoitems`. It looks like your API is returning an object instead of an array/iterable.

Comment: [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)] it shows this

Comment: Can you do a  console.log('todoitems = ' + JSON.stringify(todoitems, null, 4)); and post the output.

Comment: todoitems= [
    {
        "id": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 4
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "shafi"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "shafi"
    },
    {
        "id": 7
    },
    {
        "id": 8
    }
] @RobinWebb

Comment: Your code has confused me and I'm not sure I can help. This line looks weird...const newHero: Todo = { name } as Todo; What is this line doing ? Can you do a stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w4s7i4    totally new to this, i have included my index.js file in which i have made api request, http.service files and the app component and html @RobinWebb

Comment: Stripped out some bits https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sz2vma I think you're clearing your form before sending to http. You're using a mixture of singular and plural variable names that is confusing. And you're mixing in the hero names from tutorial. I think above link will show you the light.

Comment: @RobinWebb thank you for that, can you suggest some tutorials that i dont make these mistakes again

Answer (score 0):

I think Mostafa Bagheri might have something. In your ngOnInit method you are subscribing to an observable which falls through to a lookup to localstorage.

So you're doing a synchronous action before asynchronous observable has completed?

Without knowing your complete picture this looks wrong? Try commenting out the line commented out below to see if this suppresses your error.

If you want to get todoitems from localstorage then do this first. Check it for null and then do the observable.

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
           todoitems : [this.todolist, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)])]

        });

        this.httpService.gettodo()
        .subscribe
        (
          (      data: Todo[])=>
          {
            this.todoitems = data;
          }

        );

          //this.todoitems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todoitems'));
      }
```

### Possible alternative (not tested)

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
           todoitems : [this.todolist, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)])]

        });

        this.todoitems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todoitems'));

        if (!this.todoitems ) //check for null/undefined
        {
         this.httpService.gettodo()
        .subscribe
        (
          (      data: Todo[])=>
          {
            this.todoitems = data;
          }

        );
}




      }
```